# Creating json array for Jira multi-checkbox with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, jira

I'm receiving data in the following format from a multi-checkbox

`["Ethnicity"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Maori"]=>
    string(5) "Maori"
    ["Pacific Peoples"]=>
    string(15) "Pacific Peoples"
    ["Other European"]=>
    string(14) "Other European"
  }`

I'm trying to get this into a multi-checkbox in Jira via an API call using the following segment

```
'customfield_11337' => [
 "value" => $data["Ethnicity"]
],
```

But this returns an error `string(21) "data was not an array"`

So I've tried to massage the data into a single array using

```
$ethnicityArray = array();
    foreach ($data["Ethnicity"] as $eth => $value) {
        array_push($ethnicityArray, $value);
```

}

But this returns the same error. I should note that I've got no problem populating radio buttons, text fields etc in Jira via the same method. It just seems to be checkboxes I can't get right.

How do I go about solving this using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was to get the data into a format that looks like:

```
'customfield_11333' => [["value" => "Asian"], ["value" => "Other"]]
```